React Native CLI FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage.
Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase_app.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-firebase_app.
Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase_auth.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-firebase_auth.
Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase_firestore.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-firebase_firestore.
Could not resolve project :react-native-firebase_messaging.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-firebase_messaging.
Could not resolve project :react-native-google-signin_google-signin.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-google-signin_google-signin.
Could not resolve project :react-native-fs.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-fs.
Could not resolve project :react-native-gesture-handler.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-gesture-handler.
Could not resolve project :react-native-html-to-pdf.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-html-to-pdf.
Could not resolve project :react-native-reanimated.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-reanimated.
Could not resolve project :react-native-safe-area-context.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-safe-area-context.
Could not resolve project :react-native-screens.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-screens.
Could not resolve project :react-native-vector-icons.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-vector-icons.
Could not resolve project :rn-fetch-blob.
Required by:
project :app
> A dependency was declared on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :rn-fetch-blob.


Try:


Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 23s

Just use these commands:

npm cache clean --force
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native start --reset-cache
npx react-native run-android

No need to install the WatchMan
